# Not getting a response using Mongoose

Tags: javascript, mongoose

I am creating a document in my MongoDB database using Mongoose with the following code:

```
workoutsRouter.post('/', async (req, res) => {
  await mongoose.connect('mongodb+srv://nalanart:<password>@cluster0.2iplh.mongodb.net/workout-app-db?retryWrites=true&w=majority', 
  { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true })

  await Workout.create({
    mains: req.body.mains,
    accessories: req.body.accessories
  }, err => {
    if(err) {
      throw err
    } else {
      res.sendStatus(201)
    }
  })
})
```

My problem is that it does not send a 201 status as I have written it to. Any idea why? It just says Sending... on Postman
[image: I'm able to successfully create the document using Postman]

And here it appears in my collection:[image: this is in mongoDB atlas]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, because you are both awaiting *and* passing a callback. You are mixing the `await` and callback syntaxes. If you pass Mongoose a callback, it won't return a Promise, so it will be awaited forever, since it will never resolve. Either `await` it, *or* pass it a callback, not both. Also, try `res.status(201).end()`

```
 try {
     await Workout.create({
         mains: req.body.mains,
         accessories: req.body.accessories
     });

     res.status(201).end();
 } catch (err) {
     throw err
 }
```

Comment: Then it means Mongoose isn't connected. As long as Mongoose isn't connected to your DB, it's simply pending and doesn't throw an error. You can launch queries and everything, they'll just be pending until Mongoose connects.

Comment: got it to work now, thanks! nodemon wasn't restarting my server for some reason when I was making saves so just had to restart manually...